# Do I need to import into subclasses java

Tags: java

Suppose I have a superclass which imports java.io.Exception as an example. If I'm handling an exception in a subclass, do I need to reimport java.io.Exception into the code for the subclass?

Comment: tried it out and it didnt work before asking. Was asking to understand :) why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes (unless the two classes are in the same file).

Imports are per source code file, not per class. They are a completely compiler-only thing, with no effect at run-time.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes** if subclass is in another .java file, no otherwise

Answer (score 3):

The import scope is *per source file*<sup>1</sup>: it adds *nothing* to a class/type and thus has *nothing* to do with inheritance or subclasses.

Typing out each fully-qualified type is too cumbersome, even for Java, so imports specify how to find/resolve unqualified types (or static methods).

The compiler will kindly let you know if an import is missing when it can't resolve the type(s) ..

---

<sup>1</sup> [Import statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html) must appear *after* the package name,  if any, and *before* all types/classes declared in the file. Since there is at most one package per file, there is at most one section of imports per file and their scope encompasses the remainder of the file.